# What universal factors could alter a human DNA?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans, super-powers

Could a space-based phenomenon/radiation/light spectrum activate/alter a human genome/DNA and increase our natural abilities when returning to an Earth environment...e.g. strength, eyesight, mental functions.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please visit help center, especially "what kind of questions you shouldn't ask" part. Questions where every answer might be equally valid are not well suited for this page and likely will be put on hold.

Comment: At least, please make the title match the body. Question about energy pulses and fields is ok. Question about any factors -  I don't think so.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Artidan22, as Molot mentioned there are some (rather extensive at times) expectations on how questions and answers should be handled.  Check out the [help] as Molot mentioned to get an idea of what we are talking about.  Once you gain a little more rep you can also join us in [chat] if you have additional questions.  Hope you stick around, this is an interesting site. :)

Comment: I think it's called... exercise.

Answer (score 2):

There are no science-based mechanisms through which this can happen. Radiation exposure and other similar mechanisms is nearly almost either harmful or neutral. Even if it does somehow give a beneficial mutation that advantage will be tiny.

Humans are already extremely well adapted to our environment and only a technological intervention (for example cybernetic implants) is likely to give radical increases. Certainly telepathy and telekinesis are impossible through any mechanism we are aware of although telepathy between altered people would be possible if they had some sort of radio embedded into them.